# MongoDB Sort Array

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to sort my MongoDB array of reviews by the date the review was made? Would I have to do this in my server-side script rather than by using a query operator? If so how would I do that?

```
{
  "review": [
    {
      "date": "2012-05-04 21:06:58",
      "review": "The Review",
      "name": "The Persons Name",
    },
    {
      "date": "2012-09-04 21:06:58",
      "review": "The Review",
      "name": "The Persons Name",
    },
    {
      "date": "2012-02-04 21:06:58",
      "review": "The Review",
      "name": "The Persons Name",
    }
  ],
  "category": "Category 1",
  "country": "USA",
  "date": "2012-05-04 21:06:58"
}
```

Comment: sort review array by [usort](http://www.php.net/usort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you put [php](/questions/tagged/php) in the tags, I assume that you're working with PHP. You can create your own sorting function for this and have it called by PHP [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

```
function sort_date($a, $b)
{
    return (strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']));
}

usort($reviews_array, 'sort_date');
```

The above code will sort the reviews by date in ascending order.

Comment: A more C-ish/lazier way to write the comparator could be to just do `return (strtotime($a) - strtotime($b));`

Comment: So then I take it is impossible to do a sort like this in mongodb? Let me ask this then do you think it would be faster to use a  function like this to sort like 100 reviews or to separate the reviews from the product collection and make a reviews collection?

Comment: @cKendrick I'm not an expert on MongoDB so I can't quite say that it's impossible. I posted this answer as an alternative solution. Although if I were you, I would definitely separate the reviews into another collection.